# Do we need to submit a Document for Security Review - AppExchange?

Tags: appexchange, security-review

From the link  [Required Testing Information for the ISV Security Review](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review_Test_Info)

I found a section called **Documentation** in the above link. Do we need to submit a document described in that section.

If the [Security Review Wizard](https://partners.salesforce.com/s/education/appinnovators/Security_Review) has the same set of questions as mentioned in the documentation part as per the above link, **will there be a need to submit a separate documentation?**

Comment: Yes you will. .

Comment: @Eric Is there a option available to upload the documentation??

Comment: yes....there will be a way for you to upload your supporting documents and security policy

Comment: Hi @Eric, I have gone through the video as well as [Security Review Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/isv_security_review/isv_security_review_submit) . In step 6, there is an option to upload Other scanner reports  or documentation. Do you mean that?  We already have a Product User Manual. Thus the documentation mean User Manual or the question asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide as much as information you can. There are two section to provide the documents.

1. Scanner (Security Checks): Upload security scan document which verify that your application does not has any vulnerability. 
   Just below that you will have another option of put your explanation document if scanner report found the vulnerability but it is false as per the application use case.
2. Other documentation section is used to provide any important application details which a security engineer may ask you when they test your application. You should think and provide all use cases or technical explanation so engineer can understand the application is safe.
   This is optional but there is no harm if you have additional information and ready to provide.

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani. Just for clarification, [Security Review Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/isv_security_review/isv_security_review_submit) step 3 screen what we need to submit on behalf of company?

Comment: @DOMINICEDWARD If your company has some security policies and those are also applied to application then you should provide the document explaining what information and how you are securing it. This is not mandatory.